# How would you translate "small things that matter" in a casual way

Tags: translation, english-to-german, sentence-structure

I would like to know the translation of this:

> "Sometime it is the small thing that matters the most".

Would this sound correct in casual way

> "Manchmal kleine Dinge die meisten Fragen."

Comment: to answer your question: No, this does not sound correct. Why do you think "Fragen" should be there? Where is the verb in the German sentence?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

> Manchmal sind es die kleinen Dinge, die zählen.
>
> Manchmal zählen die kleinen Dinge am meisten.
>
> Es sind die kleinen Dinge, die zählen.

Comment: Etwas mehr Variationen als nur "zählen" wären nicht verkehrt, etwa "Kleinigkeiten geben oft den Ausschlag.".

Comment: `Kleinvieh macht auch Mist` könnte man auch hier sagen.

Comment: Manchmal geben kleine Dinge den Ausschlag.

Answer (score 3):

Mit "sind die meisten Fragen" meinst du wohl sind "die größten Probleme" - aber so sagt man nicht. Ich kenne:

> Der Teufel steckt im Detail.

Damit will man sagen, wenn es bei einem Projekt um die letzten Kleinigkeiten geht, stellt man oft fest, dass hier die eigentlichen Probleme liegen.

Comment: Gibt's auch im Englischen: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Devil_is_in_the_detail

Answer (score 3):

> Auf die kleinen Dinge kommt es an.